# Неинтерактивный режим PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Подскажите, как запустить скрипт (PS) в неинтерактивном режиме?

Comment: Требуется передать параметры?

Comment: `-NonInteractive -WindowStyle Hidden` ?

Comment: На сколько я понял, при интерактивном режиме выполняется задача с запуском PS, но при этом нет ни окна, ни вывода консоли